# NGINX proxy pass third level domain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx config like this:

```
server_name www.domain.local shop.domain.local images.domain.local;
```

and I need to write a reverse proxy to another domain like this:

```
location /checkout {
    proxy_pass https://checkout.domain2.local;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

but *only* if the domain is `shop.domain.local`.

Like `shop.domain.local/checkout => checkout.domain2.local`